# Wrapping a statement with spark.sql throws parse exception, but it runs fine with %sql magic command

Tags: apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks, databricks-sql

The following code throws error:

```
X = "CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE Invoices (InvoiceID INT, CustomerID INT, BillToCustomerID INT, OrderID INT, DeliveryMethodID INT, ContactPersonID INT, AccountsPersonID INT, SalespersonPersonID INT, PackedByPersonID INT, InvoiceDate TIMESTAMP, CustomerPurchaseOrderNumber INT, IsCreditNote STRING, CreditNoteReason STRING, Comments STRING, DeliveryInstructions STRING, InternalComments STRING, TotalDryItems INT, TotalChillerItems STRING, DeliveryRun STRING, RunPosition STRING, ReturnedDeliveryData STRING, ConfirmedDeliveryTime TIMESTAMP, ConfirmedReceivedBy STRING, LastEditedBy INT, LastEditedWhen TIMESTAMP) LOCATION '/mnt/adls/DQD/udl/Invoices/'; ALTER TABLE Invoices ADD COLUMN DQ_Check_Op SMALLINT"

spark.sql(X)
```

[image]
[image]

But, with magic command, inside a cell, it runs fine:

```
%sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE Invoices (InvoiceID INT, CustomerID INT, BillToCustomerID INT, OrderID INT, DeliveryMethodID INT, ContactPersonID INT, AccountsPersonID INT, SalespersonPersonID INT, PackedByPersonID INT, InvoiceDate TIMESTAMP, CustomerPurchaseOrderNumber INT, IsCreditNote STRING, CreditNoteReason STRING, Comments STRING, DeliveryInstructions STRING, InternalComments STRING, TotalDryItems INT, TotalChillerItems STRING, DeliveryRun STRING, RunPosition STRING, ReturnedDeliveryData STRING, ConfirmedDeliveryTime TIMESTAMP, ConfirmedReceivedBy STRING, LastEditedBy INT, LastEditedWhen TIMESTAMP) LOCATION '/mnt/adls/DQD/udl/Invoices/'; ALTER TABLE Invoices ADD COLUMN DQ_Check_Op SMALLINT
```

[image]

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my actual example, my table wasn't in the default database - I didn't think that was a relevant detail. After I wrapped my database and table name with ` (backtick), the error went off.

So, the following helped:

```
CREATE TABLE `sch`.`Invoices` (InvoiceID INT, CustomerID INT, BillToCustomerID INT, OrderID INT, DeliveryMethodID INT, ContactPersonID INT, AccountsPersonID INT, SalespersonPersonID INT, PackedByPersonID INT, InvoiceDate TIMESTAMP, CustomerPurchaseOrderNumber INT, IsCreditNote STRING, CreditNoteReason STRING, Comments STRING, DeliveryInstructions STRING, InternalComments STRING, TotalDryItems INT, TotalChillerItems STRING, DeliveryRun STRING, RunPosition STRING, ReturnedDeliveryData STRING, ConfirmedDeliveryTime TIMESTAMP, ConfirmedReceivedBy STRING, LastEditedBy INT, LastEditedWhen TIMESTAMP) LOCATION '/mnt/repro/';ALTER TABLE `sch`.`Invoices` ADD COLUMN DQ_Check_Op SMALLINT"
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting a `ParseException` in `spark.sql` is because of the usage of multiple SQL query statements (`CREATE` and `ALTER`) with the help of `;` . Pyspark is not reading this query in the same way as Databricks SQL. Databricks SQL is able to parse and execute multiple queries separated by a semicolon. But Pyspark throws a ParseException while reading any statement written after semicolon.

So, using a single query with `spark.sql` is recommended (single line query or multiline query) instead of using a single `spark.sql` to execute multiple SQL queries.

The workaround using Pyspark SQL would be to use one `spark.sql` for each SQL query. You can modify your code as following:

```
X = "CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE Invoices (InvoiceID INT, CustomerID INT, BillToCustomerID INT, OrderID INT, DeliveryMethodID INT, ContactPersonID INT, AccountsPersonID INT, SalespersonPersonID INT, PackedByPersonID INT, InvoiceDate TIMESTAMP, CustomerPurchaseOrderNumber INT, IsCreditNote STRING, CreditNoteReason STRING, Comments STRING, DeliveryInstructions STRING, InternalComments STRING, TotalDryItems INT, TotalChillerItems STRING, DeliveryRun STRING, RunPosition STRING, ReturnedDeliveryData STRING, ConfirmedDeliveryTime TIMESTAMP, ConfirmedReceivedBy STRING, LastEditedBy INT, LastEditedWhen TIMESTAMP) LOCATION '/mnt/repro/';"

Y = "ALTER TABLE Invoices ADD COLUMN DQ_Check_Op SMALLINT"

z = "SELECT * FROM Invoices"

spark.sql(X)
spark.sql(Y)
spark.sql(z)
```

[image]

Comment: That's not quite right. In my actual example, my table wasn't in the default database. After I wrapped my database and table name with ` (backtick), the error went off. I didn't think that's a relevant detail, so I didn't mention a non-default database. But, the premise of your answer is incorrect that you can't pass multiple SQL query statements to spark.sql.

Comment: Hey @SouravA, the additional query after semicolon was causing the issue while I tried to reproduce it. Thank you for correcting me. Consider posting the answer in detail so it will be helpful.